# Do Timers run on their Own threads in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a bit confused here I know Javascript is a single-threaded language but while reading about the event loop. I got to know that in case of setTimeout or setInterval javascript calls web API provided by the browser which spawns a new thread to execute timer on that thread. but what happens in the case of node.js environment with timers how do they execute/work?

Comment: note: nodejs is not written in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No threads are used for timers in node.js.

Timers in node.js work in conjunction with the event loop and don't use a thread.  Timers in node.js are stored in a sorted linked list with the next timer to fire at the start of the linked list.  Each time through the event loop, it checks to see if the first timer in the linked list has reached its time.  If so, it fires that timer.  If not, it runs any other events that are waiting in the event loop.

On each subsequent cycle through the event loop, it keeps checking to see if its time for the next timer or not.  When a new timer is added, it is inserted into the linked list in its proper sorted order.  When it fires or is cancelled, it is removed from the linked list.

If the event loop has nothing to do, it may sleep for a brief period of time, but it won't sleep past the timer for the next timer.

Other references on the topic:

[How does nodejs manage timers internally](https://asafdav2.github.io/2017/node-js-timers/)

[Libuv timer code in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538323/does-the-nodejs-libuv-event-loop-execute-all-the-callbacks-in-one-phase-queue/60558590#60558590)

[How many concurrent setTimeouts before performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276583/how-many-concurrent-settimeouts-before-performance-issues/38277310#38277310)

[Multiple Client Requests in NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982001/multiple-client-requests-in-nodejs/60983863#60983863)

[Looking for a solution between setting lots of timers or using a scheduled task queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655705/looking-for-a-solution-between-setting-lots-of-timers-or-using-a-scheduled-task/59656871#59656871)

Answer (score 1):

Node runs on a single thread but asynchronous work happens elsewhere. For example, libuv provides a pool of 4 threads that it may use, but wont if there's a better option.

The node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/) says

> Node.js runs JavaScript code in the Event Loop (initialization and callbacks), and offers a Worker Pool to handle expensive tasks like file I/O. Node.js scales well, sometimes better than more heavyweight approaches like Apache. The secret to the scalability of Node.js is that it uses a small number of threads to handle many clients. If Node.js can make do with fewer threads, then it can spend more of your system's time and memory working on clients rather than on paying space and time overheads for threads (memory, context-switching). But because Node.js has only a few threads, you must structure your application to use them wisely.

A more [detailed](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c) look at the event loop

Comment: This is correct but there are no threads involved with timers at all. The documentation clearly states that threads are used only for four things: disk I/O, DNS resolver (there is no asynchronous API for this on most OS), zip and gzip compression and some cryptographic functions

Answer (score 0):

No. Timers are just scheduled on the same thread and will call their callbacks when the time expires.

Depending on what OS your are on and what javascript interpreters you use they will use various APIs form `poll` to `epoll` to `kqueue` to overlapped I/O on Windows but in general asynchronous APIs have similar features. So let's ignore platform differences and look at a cross-platform API that exists on all OSes: the POSIX `select()` system call.

The [select](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man2/select.2.html) function in C looks something like this:

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
              fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

Where `nfds` is total number of file descriptors (including network sockets) you are waiting/listening on, `readfds` is the list/set of read file descriptors you are waiting on, `writefds` is the list/set of write file descriptors, `exceptfds` is the list/set of error file descriptors (think stderr) and `timeval` is the timeout for the function.

This system call blocks - yes, in non-blocking, asynchronous code there is a piece of blocking system call. The main difference between non-blocking code and blocking threaded code is that the entire program blocks in only one place, the `select()` function (or whatever equivalent you use).

This function only returns if any of the file descriptors have activity on them or if the timeout expires.

By managing the timeout and calculating the next value of `timeval` you can implement a function like `setTimeout`

I've written much deeper explanations of how this works in answers to the following related questions:

[I know that callback function runs asynchronously, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883525/i-know-that-callback-function-runs-asynchronously-but-why/29885509#29885509)

[Event Queuing in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291520/event-queuing-in-nodejs/30291679#30291679)

[how node.js server is better than thread based server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759683/how-node-js-server-is-better-than-thread-based-server/3759991#3759991)

[Node js architecture and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101877/node-js-architecture-and-performance/49102055#49102055)

[Performance of NodeJS with large amount of callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961698/performance-of-nodejs-with-large-amount-of-callbacks/56713809#56713809)

[Does javascript process using an elastic racetrack algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616477/does-javascript-process-using-an-elastic-racetrack-algorithm/19620041#19620041)

[Is there any other way to implement a "listening" function without an infinite while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262054/is-there-any-other-way-to-implement-a-listening-function-without-an-infinite-w/61826079#61826079)

I recommend you at least browse each of the answers I wrote above because they are almost all non-duplicates. They sometimes overlap but explain different aspects of asynchronous code execution.

The gist of it is that javascript does not execute code in parallel to implement timers. It doesn't need to. Instead it **waits** in parallel. Once you understand the difference between running code in parallel and waiting (doing nothing) in parallel you will understand how things like node.js achieve high performance and how events work better.